# Console in Intellij is not showing any problem when application is crashing

Tags: intellij-idea, error-handling

everyone :)
I am trying to remember how to work on Intellij Community Edition 2018.1 (I used Eclipse for while now) and I cannot find where the errors might been shown in the console. I am trying to create a new application and when I try to access one of the link, I receive in browser a 404 not found error, but in Intellij console I have no error. 
Is it there a configuration for that? 
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more details about your project. Is it a web app? What run/debug configuration is used in IntelliJ IDEA? How does the app log the errors?

Comment: It is a web application based on Spring Boot and I added log4j in the dependencies.

Comment: So, where does this error go with your app configuration? Which log file contains more details?

Comment: If 404 is originally caused by missing resource, it might not be reflected in the log (catalina.out or custom log file). It will be only reflected in access.log of your app server, however IDEA's console isn't feeding from there by default.